# Remove a Canvas Child by tag

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I have an ellipse (prew) that I want to delete from canvas (canvas1) by tag ("p").
I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
var child = (from c in canvas1.Children
             where "p".Equals(c.Tag)
             select c).First();
canvas1.Children.Remove(child);
```

It gave me this error:

> "Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type
>   'System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection'.  'Where' not found. 
>   Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'c'."

How can I remove a `canvas` child by tag?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `UIElementCollection` implements plain old `IEnumerable` and hence isn't compatible with LINQ by default.  You need to convert it to a strongly typed `IEnumerable<T>` before querying

```
var child = (from c in canvas1.Children.Cast<FrameworkElement>()
             where "p".Equals(c.Tag)
             select c).First();
canvas1.Children.Remove(child);
```

Note that this code is suspectible to a runtime error if there is a non `FrameworkElement` in the collection (another derivation of `UIElement`).  To protect against this you are probably better off going to the `OfType` method

```
var child = (from c in canvas1.Children.OfType<FrameworkElement>()
             where "p".Equals(c.Tag)
             select c).First();
canvas1.Children.Remove(child);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var child = (from FrameworkElement c in canvas1.Children
             where "p".Equals(c.Tag)
             select c).First();
canvas1.Children.Remove(child);
```

or

```
var child = (from c in canvas1.Children.Cast<FrameworkElement>()
             where "p".Equals(c.Tag)
             select c).First();
canvas1.Children.Remove(child);
```